# Pull out values from dataarray corresponding to dataframe entry

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-xarray

I have a dataarray with data at lat,lon points. I have a dataframe with a list of port names and their lat and lon. I want to marry the two together to pull out values from the array that correspond to specific lat,lon points associated with ports and add a new column in the dataframe with the value.

array:

```
<xarray.DataArray (lat: 109, lon: 327)>
array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]])
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) float64 -52.0 -51.0 -50.0 -49.0 -48.0 ... 53.0 54.0 55.0 56.0
  * lon      (lon) float64 28.0 29.0 30.0 31.0 32.0 ... 351.0 352.0 353.0 354.0
```

dataframe:

```
Latitude    Longitude   Port Name
0   39.871112   20.003421   Sarande
1   40.450605   19.483051   Vlora
2   41.810046   19.584720   Shengjin
3   41.308849   19.454677   Durres
4   35.819101   -0.247319   Bettioua
```

Ideal output would look like this:

```
Latitude    Longitude   Port Name    Value
    0   39.871112   20.003421   Sarande    0
    1   40.450605   19.483051   Vlora      1
    2   41.810046   19.584720   Shengjin   2
    3   41.308849   19.454677   Durres     3
    4   35.819101   -0.247319   Bettioua   4
```

I have tried converting the array into a dataframe and merging the two together but could not produce the result i was looking for. Have also tried using `np.sort()` on the array and creating a dataframe from that, but also did not result in the end.

Comment: When you tried the merge, did you make the join condition round the values to the same number of decimal places? In the DataArray, I see latitudes/longitudes given to 1 decimal place, whereas there are 6 decimal places in the DataFrame. E.g. 39.9 != 39.871112.